# MS SQL Server not using index when WHERE has IN with more than 6 values

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, table-index

So i have a very strange issue, If i run a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_x 
WHERE tbl_x.SomeCode IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6')
```

The query uses the index on the table, however if i do query this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl_x 
WHERE tbl_x.SomeCode IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7')
```

The query ignores the index and decides to do a Table Scan

Why is MS SQL Server not using the index when there are more than 6 values in the Where clause?

Comment: IF an index is very fragmented (say 50%) SQL Server might decide to just scan rather than use the index since it thinks this is the "cheaper" plan.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that based on data distribution and cardinality query optimizer decides to use full table scan, because it is cheaper than to use index.

You could check:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_x;
```

and

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_x
WHERE tbl_x.SomeCode IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7');
```

Probably you exceeded 20% rows of entire table.

Comment: What do you mean about 20% of the entire table?

Comment: @MikeBateman I mean 20% of rows, for example if first query returns 5000 and second 1001 rows.